# Recursive Binary Description

Tags: code-golf

## Recursive Binary Description

Recently, I made my very first contribution to OEIS by extending and adding a b-file to sequence [A049064](https://oeis.org/A049064). The sequence starts with `0`, and then the next values are derived from giving a "binary description" of the last item.

For example, the second term would be `10`, because there was one `0` in the first element. The third term would be `1110`, because there was one `1` and one `0`. The fourth would be `11110`. because there are three **(`11` in binary!)** `1`s and one `0`. Below is a breakdown of the fifth term to make this process clear:

```
> 11110
> 1111 0    (split into groups of each number)
> 4*1 1*0   (get count of each number in each group)
> 100*1 1*0 (convert counts to binary)
> 100110    (join each group back together)
```

And here's an example for going from the 6th to the 7th term:

```
> 1110010110
> 111 00 1 0 11 0
> 3*1 2*0 1*1 1*0 2*1 1*0
> 11*1 10*0 1*1 1*0 10*1 1*0
> 111100111010110
```

You can check out a reference program<sup>φ</sup> I made to calculate the terms.

## Your Job

You need to create a *program or function* which takes in a number `n` via *standard input or function arguments*, and prints out the sequence from the `1st` term to the `(n+1)th` term, separated by a newline. If you would like a look at the lower numbers, you may refer to the b-file from the OEIS page. However, your program/function should support `0 <= n <= 30`, i.e. up to the 31st term. This is no small feat, as `A049064(30)` is over 140,000 digits long<sup>δ</sup>. If you would like to see what the 31st term should be, I've put it on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ZpqSVJvQ).

## Example I/O

```
func(10)
0
10
1110
11110
100110
1110010110
111100111010110
100110011110111010110
1110010110010011011110111010110
1111001110101100111001011010011011110111010110
1001100111101110101100111100111010110111001011010011011110111010110

func(0)
0

func(3)
0
10
1110
11110
```

There is only one rule: **No standard loopholes!**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest byte count wins.

---

<sup>φ - Gist can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/kade-robertson/d7e2c14975ef45063455), and an ideone demo is [here](http://ideone.com/zLFrFG).</sup>

<sup>δ - Just in case you were wondering, my estimates at the length of the 100th term put it at approximately 3.28x10<sup>250</sup> characters long, which would be quite a lot for anyone to calculate.</sup>

Comment: Output as list allowed? Like `[0]\n[1, 0]\n[1, 1, 1, 0]\n...`

Comment: @Jakube No, you'll need to do a string join on it.

Comment: Congrats on making a contribution to OEIS!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## CJam, <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
0{sN1$e`2af.b}ri*
```

*Thanks to @MartinBüttner for golfing off one byte!*

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=0%7BsN1%24e%602af.b%7Dri*&input=10).

#### How it works

```
0                 e# Push 0.
 {           }ri* e# Repeat int(input)) times:
  s               e#   Stringify the element on top of the stack.
                       EXAMPLE: [[[1 1] '1] [[1] '0]] -> "11110"
   N              e#   Push a linefeed.
    1$            e#   Copy the last stack.
      e`          e#   Perform run-length encoding.
                  e#   EXAMPLE: "100110" -> [[1 '1] [2 '0] [2 '1] [1 '0]]
        2a        e#   Push [2].
          f.b     e#   For each pair [x 'y], execute: [x 'y][2].b
                  e#   This pushes [x2b 'y], where b is base conversion.
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
J]0VQjk~JsjR2srJ8
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J]0VQjk~JsjR2srJ8&input=10&debug=0)

Thanks to @isaacg for saving one byte.

#### Explanation:

```
                     implicit: Q = input number
 ]0                  create an initial list [0]
J                    and store in J
   VQ                for loop, repeat Q times:
              rJ8       run-length-encoding of J
             s          sum, unfolds lists
          jR2           convert each value to base 2
         s              sum, unfolds lists
       ~J               store the result in J

                        but return the old list,
     jk                 join it and print it
```

This uses the fact, that 0 and 1 in binary are also 0 and 1.

Comment: This is 1 byte shorter using `V` instead of `.u`: `J]0VQjk~JsjR2srJ8`

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>125</s> <s>116</s> 110 bytes

```
from itertools import*
v='0'
exec"print v;v=''.join(bin(len(list(g)))[2:]+k for k,g in groupby(v));"*-~input()
```

Saved 1 byte thanks to @Sp3000 and 5 bytes by removing a redundant `int` call.

Older version:

```
import itertools as t
v='0'
exec"print v;v=''.join(bin(int(len(list(g))))[2:]+k for k,g in t.groupby(v));"*-~input()
```

Saved many, many bytes thanks to @Vioz-!

Original version:

```
import itertools as t
v='0'
for n in range(input()+1):print v;v=''.join(bin(int(len(list(g))))[2:]+k for k,g in t.groupby(v))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 37 bytes

```
{,/{(,/$2\#x),*x}'(&~~':x)_x}\[;,"0"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlpHv1pDR1/FKEa5QlNHq6JWXUOtrk7dqkIzvqI2JtpaR8lAKfZ/mrqhgYKBgvF/AA)

- `{...}\[;,"0"]` set up a scan, seeded with `,"0"` and run for a number of times equal to the (implicit) input
- `(&~~':x)_x` split into groups of the same characters
- `{...}'` for each group...

  - `(,/$2\#x)` get the binary representation of the count of each group
  - `(...),*x` append the first character of each group (i.e. whether it is a group of `0`s or of `1`s)
- `,/` flatten the results and feed to the next iteration of the scan

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>80</s> <s>72</s> 69 bytes

As a function:

```
f=->m{l=?0;0.upto(m){puts l;l.gsub!(/1+|0+/){$&.size.to_s(2)+$&[0]}}}
```

Call it for example with: `f[6]`

Comment: You could save a few bytes if you take input as a function argument: `->m{l=?0;0.upto(m){puts l;l.gsub!(/1+|0+/){$&.size.to_s(2)+$&[0]}}}`

Comment: @blutorange Nice! Totally forgot about `upto` and `!`  -- Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 102 bytes

```py
import re
o='0'
exec"print o;o=''.join(bin(len(x))[2:]+x[0]for x in re.findall('0+|1+',o));"*-~input()
```

Somehow the combination of `itertools` being longer than `re` and `groupby` returning `grouper` objects means that using regex is a bit shorter...

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <sup><s>16</s></sup> 14 bytes

```
µṄŒrUFV€BFṾ€ø¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q1oc7W45OKgp1C3vUtMbJ7eHOfUD68I5DC///NwUA)

<del>I still feel like there's some better way to do the string printing.</del>

-2 bytes from xigoi.

Comment: You can convert numbers to strings with `Ṿ`, the opposite of `V`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ŒrUBFƲÐ¡Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opKJQJ7djmw5POLQw8v9/QwMA)

Takes input from STDIN.

### Explanation

```
ŒrUBFƲÐ¡Y   Main niladic link
            Implicitly start with 0
      Ð¡    Repeat [number from STDIN] times and collect all values
     Ʋ      (
Œr            Run-length encode -> [[digit, repetitions], ...]
  U           Reverse each sublist -> [[repetitions, digit], ...]
   B          Convert all numbers to binary
    F         Flatten
     Ʋ      )
        Y   Join by newlines
            The numbers are automatically concatenated
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, <s>136</s> 130 Bytes

```
import Text.Printf
import Data.List
f n=putStr.unlines.take(n+1).iterate(concatMap(\n->(printf"%b"$length n)++[head n]).group)$"0"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Cobra - 128

```cobra
do(i)=if(i-=1,(r=RegularExpressions).Regex.replace(f(i),'1+|0+',do(m=r.Match())=Convert.toString('[m]'.length,2)+'[m]'[:1]),'0')
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
î╩∩▬╒«ç╚¢↓}~
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8ccaef16d5ae87c89b197d7e&i=10%0A0%0A3&m=2)